# How do I earn the Proofreader badge?

Tags: support, review, badges

How does one go about earning the [Proofreader badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader)? I have attempted looking at other answers and couldn't find much.

Is there a detailed process that could be explained please?

Comment: I wouldn't mark this as a duplicate. When searching for "How do I earn a Proofreader badge?" this won't come up for most users hence I asked the question.

Comment: That's *exactly* the purpose of duplicate questions; they serve as [signposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144608/295232).

Comment: Ok I see but this page you marked as a duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for is extremely broad and brief. My question is directed at this Proofreader badge _specifically and with more detail_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) lists all the available badges.
In your case you want to look at the description for the [Proofreader one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader).

> Approve or reject 100 suggested edits.

This means that -once you gain enough rep - you will have to work on [this review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) (available from the link on the top left of the site header and perform at least 100 successful reviews.

The access to the Edit Suggestion review queue is tied to other privileges you can gain with enough reputation points. In this specific case, you should at least have the [Edit Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege - which is available once you reach 2000 rep point on a site (notice that to review suggested edits to tag wiki pages you need the [Approve tag wiki edits privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), available at 5000 rep point. So until that, you will have access only to a subset of the available reviews).

Final disclaimer: all the links in this answer are relative to *this site*, so please refer to the specific pages on your site of interests if you need more details or want to check your progress.

---

A little clarification since it was asked in comments. First, yep, it is technically possible to get the badge before reaching 2000 rep score - but that means all your reviews must come from suggested edits to your own posts. Unless one tries to game the system, that probably won't happen very often.

Second... the [Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page lists **all the available badges** including ones that you can't get yet (example: Citized Patrol if you don't yet have the ability to flag posts) or ones that can't be awarded anymore (example: [Precognitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/precognitive) for a site that is already past its commitment phase).

It is worth noticing that the badge tracker tool available in the user profile page does instead provide the ability to filter out not-yet obtainable badges.

[image]

To access the badge progress tracking selection window click on the small gear icon shown on your user profile near the badge name.

[image]

As you can see, you have multiple tabs. The last one, "Available" only list badges that you are actually eligible for at the moment.
In that merit it is worth noticing that the Proofreader badge is indeed shown on the available tab for <2k rep users because as we said before it is still technically available to them, just very hard to get without gaming the system.

Comment: That page is a bit terse. See also *[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)*

Comment: Thanks - I don't understand why it is available to users that don't have 2000 reputation then?

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw - what do you mean by "available"? The fact that it is visible in the badge list? If that is the case... the [badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) help page lists all the available badges, including the ones that you can't get yet and even some that you probably [can't get anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/precognitive) .

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks for shedding some light on that. I had the perception that the badges that are available ("shown") were the ones you could get with your current reputation.

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw see my edit - I think that may shed some more light on the topic

Comment: Thanks - strange that it is under the Available section.

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw As I said (and Glorfindel too, before I did) you are always allowed to review suggested edits that were made to one of your posts. This means that - at least theoretically - an user could perform all the 100 reviews required to get the Proofreader badge just by approving/rejecting edits that were suggested on your posts. I doubt anyone has actually ever got the badge that way, but it is still possible to, that's why the badge is listed as "available".

Comment: Extremely confusing for any new user, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to earn the [privilege to review Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), which is at 2000 reputation (or 1000 reputation for Beta sites). Then, you'll gain access to the [Suggested Edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), where you have to complete 100 review tasks.

Since you're always allowed to review suggested edits on your own posts, regardless of your reputation, it is *in theory* possible to earn the badge without 2000 reputation. But most of the times, those 100 posts (or slightly less if some posts are edited multiple times) will already earn you the reputation if they're at least moderately useful. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1012998/sub-2k-users-with-a-lot-of-suggested-edit-reviews-on-own-posts) shows one user who is almost halfway (43/100) this scenario, though.

Comment: It's possible to game the badge by logging out and suggesting anonymous edits, then logging back in and reviewing them.

Comment: Why is this badge available to users without 2000 reputation then?